# Rate Limiting in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a rate limiting in nginx associated with header q in http block as follows:

```
map $http_q $r_b001 {
        b001 "b001";
        default "";
}

limit_req_zone $r_b001 zone=r_b001:5m rate=50r/s;

map $http_q $r_c001 {
        c001 "c001";
        default "";
}

limit_req_zone $r_c001 zone=r_c001:5m rate=100r/s;

map $http_q $r_d001 {
        d001 "d001";
        default "";
}

limit_req_zone $r_d001 zone=r_d001:5m rate=150r/s;
```

So each time when I test with each key (b001, c001, d001 respectively) with less QPS limit (40r/s, 90r/s, 140r/s) from Jmeter, I get some error values always.

And even if I use 50 Req/sec for d001 (limited to 150r/s) I get some error percent always.

In server block I limit req with respective zone as follows:

```
limit_req zone=r_b001 burst=1 nodelay;
limit_req zone=r_c001 burst=1 nodelay;
limit_req zone=r_d001 burst=1 nodelay;
```

Can you point me where the configuration has gone wrong? or if the order is important for multiple rate limiting with respective to a header value.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/630157/whats-the-meaning-of-defining-burst-with-nodelay-option